# To verify whether my startdate or enddate of a node falls within the specific date range

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on a query based on the following scenario.
I have a node with start and end dates and I want to check either the startdate or enddate falls within the requested time range then return all properties within the nodes.
For instance, startdate on a node is 08-06 and enddate is 08-09 and user params are 08-07 and 08-10, because 08-09 falls within the requested range, give me the result of the entire node. I tried some combinations and nothing worked!

```
// this is giving me records that will not fall under the required ranges.
WHERE
  (l.startdate>="08-07" and l.enddate<="08-10") or
  (l.startdate<="08-07" and l.enddate<="08-10")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
WHERE
  "08-07" <= l.startdate <= "08-10" OR
  "08-07" <= l.enddate <= "08-10"
```